# 0x1 error on Python script execution from Task Scheduler

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run script (`script1.py`) from `windows task scheduler`. The script is supposed to control Chrome `webdriver` and I believe it could be the root of the problem.

> Result is 0x1.

Before creating the task I tested the execution of `script1.py` directly from `cmd` and it works.

So I've created script which writes into the file in the same location as `script1.py`, than created task - `0x0`, record is added to the file.

works:

```
<Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>/c C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\python.exe d:\folder\write_dummy_file.py</Arguments>
</Exec>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>/c C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\python.exe d:\folder\script1.py</Arguments>
</Exec>
```

The task to run `write_dummy_file.py` was created from `xml` file of the task to run `script1.py`.

Those are modules used in the problem script1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from datetime import datetime
import time
import win32com.client as comclt
import pickledb
```

In the logs I see "Action started", "Action completed", "Task completed".
In the Task Manager I can see multiple instances of the Chromedriver, but expected job is not done - browser was never opened.

Comment: What does the Event Log say?

Comment: Thanks thebjorn, I updated my question

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Since we deal with webdriver in the script, the execution should be visible. 
Task has to be set for "*Run only when user is logged in*", otherwise it ran in background and failed (it was set to "Run whether user is logged on or not").

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I searched all kinds of ways on Google that were unsuccessful. Finally, I found that the reason for the execution failure was that my py script had a third-party library that was not installed in Python (the script worked well in spyder, but "DLL load failed" in python.exe)hoping to help people in similar situations